# Expression must be an lvalue

Tags: c++

There are a lot of such questions, but going through them didn't solve problem in my case.

The `PSSetShaderResources` as a 3rd parameter wants `ID3DShaderResourceView* const*`.

so I cannot make it this way (because I am getting the lvalue error):

```
// std::unique_ptr<Texture> mTexture;
// ID3D11ShaderResourceView* Texture::getTexture() const {
//     return mTexture;
// }

deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources( 0U, 1U, &mTexture->getTexture() );
```

That's why I found a way around to make it this way:

```
auto tex = mTexture->getTexture();
deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources( 0U, 1U, &tex );
```

However, I'd like to get rid of the `auto tex = ...` line. **Is there any possibility to change the getTexture() method (or without changing it) to write just as in the first case?**

Comment: Judging by the name `PSSetShaderResources` I guess the function wants to *set* the pointer, which is the reason you have to pass a pointer to a pointer. When you call it with `getTexture` you're giving it a pointer to a *temporary*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but if I use `auto tex = ...` it is a temporary too (it will be removed when we leave the method in which the tex resides in) and it still works.

Comment: @tobi tex is a temporary for you, but the compiler doesn't know that, and it's just an ordinary variable and thus not a temporary for the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have solved it by changing the `getTexture()` method to:

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* const* Texture::getTexture() const {
    return &mTexture.p; // this is a CComPtr<ID3DShaderResourceView> mTexture;
}
```